# wubi installed ubuntu 11.10 wont boot

Tags: 11.10, wubi, windows-xp

after reboot (which wubi prompted me to do) i choose ubuntu and a few lines of code and i press escape and choose normal mode ,the screen fills with code i then get a blinking cursor for about 30 seconds the cursor goes away and the screen is blank (the same thing happens when i choose other modes) i normally run windows xp

p.s. this is my first time trying to use ubuntu so i guess im a noob

Comment: Try adding nomodeset: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10089820&postcount=8

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if you are having a problem with your graphics card. If that is the case, re-installing wubi is not going to help.

I suggest you burn a CD or make a bootable USB and try ubuntu "Live".

See:

CD - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

USB - http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

It would help if you can tell us what graphics card you have.

Comment: where did you tell us what graphics card you have? I missed the information

Answer (score 0):

you can reinstall wubi im also use wubi on my windows 7 pc while installation does not press esc :-)